# Git fetches aren't replicating in local working copy

Tags: git

For a web development class focusing on using Groovy/Grails, the professor is requiring the use of git as the version control and repository.  My team is using Google Code as the remote repository.  On my local machine, I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite, an Eclipse branch with integrated Groovy and Grails compatibility, as well as Egit.  This last bit is a source of irritation, as I'm very used to SVN for personal and small team (< 3 people) usage.  Git isn't clicking for me as SVN does.

My issue is my changes get replicated to the repository, but the remote changes aren't being replicated in the local working copy.

For example, I've executed fetch and pull.  According to those commands, my local copy is at the head revision, yet there are three new files in the remote repository that aren't showing up in the local working copy.

Literally, the only solution I've been able to come up with is to delete the local working copy and do a clone of the repository.  This solution is just a stopgap, however.

Any ideas as to what is preventing the remote changes to being replicated on the local working copy?

Comment: git pull is defined as a combination of fetch and merge.  As that didn't work either, would merge alone be appropriate?

Comment: Are you sure you are 1. pulling 2. from the right location? Is Egit transparent about what it does; if not, have you tried using git in shell directly?

Comment: +1 for trying the shell, also are you sure you are pulling/verifying the correct branch?

Comment: What do you mean "it's at the head revision"? The "head revision" of the remote repo? As others said, are you pulling the right branch? If you run `gitk --all` does your problem become obvious?

Comment: Do you have the ability to run a command from the shell? If so, please run `git remote show origin` and update the question with the result of that command.